# Blender model is silver / metallic grey in Tabletop Simulator and doesn't take texture

Tags: blender, 3d-model, tabletop-simulator

I'm attempting to create a very basic hexagonal cylinder for the board of a board game.  I've finally figured out how to make the model, export it as an .obj and import that into Tabletop Simulator via my website.

When the model is imported, it seems to be the correct shape, but is a metallic grey / silver and won't accept the texture I'm trying to use.

How do I get it to accept textures?

And / or, how do I get the template from the model to align the texture for the model correctly?

Object is as follows: (I did remove the .mtl file reference and .blend reference in an attempt to get it to work)

```
# Blender v2.77 (sub 0) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
o Cylinder
v 0.000000 -0.051057 -6.905935
v 0.000000 0.020701 -6.905935
v 5.980715 -0.051057 -3.452967
v 5.980715 0.020701 -3.452967
v 5.980715 -0.051057 3.452968
v 5.980715 0.020701 3.452968
v -0.000000 -0.051057 6.905935
v -0.000000 0.020701 6.905935
v -5.980715 -0.051057 3.452966
v -5.980715 0.020701 3.452966
v -5.980715 -0.051057 -3.452967
v -5.980715 0.020701 -3.452967
vn 0.5000 0.0000 -0.8660
vn 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn 0.5000 0.0000 0.8660
vn -0.5000 0.0000 0.8660
vn 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
vn -1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn -0.5000 0.0000 -0.8660
vn 0.0000 -1.0000 0.0000
usemtl Material
s off
f 2//1 3//1 1//1
f 4//2 5//2 3//2
f 6//3 7//3 5//3
f 8//4 9//4 7//4
f 2//5 10//5 6//5
f 10//6 11//6 9//6
f 12//7 1//7 11//7
f 3//8 7//8 11//8
f 2//1 4//1 3//1
f 4//2 6//2 5//2
f 6//3 8//3 7//3
f 8//4 10//4 9//4
f 6//5 4//5 2//5
f 2//5 12//5 10//5
f 10//5 8//5 6//5
f 10//6 12//6 11//6
f 12//7 2//7 1//7
f 11//8 1//8 3//8
f 3//8 5//8 7//8
f 7//8 9//8 11//8
```

Comment: I expect you need to [uvunwrap or check that the uv's are exported](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35401582/2684771)

Comment: @sambler Thank you and thank you for the link: it looks like what I need, hopefully it works out when I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @sambler I was put on the right track and found a couple of tutorials for unwrapping a model properly.

I even got one model with a correct UV Map.

I'm having trouble on the other models (and the same one when I open it now) moving uv vertices without moving the same one in another seam, but I'll post that as another issues somewhere.